# Is this assumption in the linear span equality proof valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Question:** Let $S=\{\alpha,\beta\}$ and $T=\{\alpha,\beta,\alpha + \beta\}$. Show that $L(S)=L(T)$.

---

**My Attempt:**

Firstly, we assume that $\gamma \in L(T)$. 
So, $\gamma = c_1\alpha+c_2\beta+c_3(\alpha + \beta)$ where $c_i \in \mathbb{F}\,\, \forall \,\, i$

We can rearrange this as $\gamma = (c_1+c_3)\alpha+(c_2+c_3)\beta=b_1\alpha+b_2\beta$ where $b_1=(c_1+c_3) \in \mathbb{F}$ and $b_2=(c_2+c_3) \in \mathbb{F}$

Hence, $\gamma \in L(T) \implies \gamma \in L(S)$.
So, $\boxed{L(S) \subset L(T)}$.

Similarly, I can reverse the argument and assume that $\gamma \in L(S)$. 
So, $\gamma = d_1\alpha+d_2\beta$ where $d_i \in \mathbb{F}\,\, \forall \,\, i$

Now let $\large\color{blue}{0 \le d<\min(d_1,d_2)}$

We can rearrange this as $\gamma = (d_1-d)\alpha+(d_2-d)\beta+d(\alpha + \beta)=e_1\alpha+e_2\beta+e_3(\alpha + \beta)$ where $e_1=(d_1-d) \in \mathbb{F}$, $e_2=(d_2-d) \in \mathbb{F}$ and $e_3=d \in \mathbb{F}$.

Hence, $\gamma \in L(S) \implies \gamma \in L(T)$.
So, $\boxed{L(T) \subset L(S)}$.

From the boxed statements, I conclude that $L(T) = L(S)$.

---

**Now, my question is:** *Does the $d$ mentioned in the colored line always exist?* If it does, then surely my proof is correct. But if that assumption is not always valid, then what do I do to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step with $d$ is not necessary, since the implication $L(S)\subset L(T)$ is immediate. If $γ=d_1\alpha+d_2\beta$, then already $γ\in L(T)$ since $γ\in \text{span}\{\alpha, \beta\}\subset \text{span}\{\alpha,\beta,\alpha+\beta\}=L(T)$. Equivalently, $$γ=d_1\alpha+d_2\beta=d_1\alpha+d_2\beta+0(\alpha+\beta)$$ In your answer you do not need to impose that $d\ge 0$. You can take any $d\in \mathbb F$, but by the above doing this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

And to answer the first part of your question about the existence of $d$: **no**, for a couple reasons.

- First, not all fields can be ordered, so if $\mathbb{F}$ is, say, the field of complex numbers, then $0\le d$ etc. do not even make any sense.
- Second, even if $\mathbb{F}$ is ordered (e.g. the real numbers), then you can still have both $d_1\le 0$ and $d_2\le0$, and then you would need $0\le d<0$, which is not possible.